# Why does a function have multiple pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I am doing a relatively simple task but I do not understand the wider context / application purpose for it:

```c
void ft_multipointer(int *********nbr)
{
  *********nbr = 99;
}
```

1. In which scenario could I use/ need so many pointers?
2. Is the term `nbr` mandatory or could I write any other letter sequence there?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Depending on project design, it's rare to go past level 2 and even rarer past 3 (Nginx, for example, uses 4-level pointers somewhere). / 2. Go read books, it's just a regular function argument that you could use any valid identifier for.

Comment: Beware the [Three-Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) — run as fast as possible from a Nine-Star Programmer.  How are you going to write the calling code?  It is painful beyond belief, even to think about.

Comment: *In which scenario could I use/ need so many pointers?* If you have to ask, the answer is an absolute and unequivocal "Never".

Comment: You would never need so many pointers. And `nbr` is just a parameter name.

Comment: ..."could I write any other letter sequence there" - no, you cannot use a [reserved word](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wdfrhcw/1.3.0?topic=programs-c-reserved-keywords).

Comment: If you have a 9-dimensional array, this would be how you would pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @Barmar: No — you'd pass a 9D array by specifying the dimensions.  For a 9-star pointer, you'd need something like: `int v; int *p1 = &v; int **p2 = &p1; int ***p3 = &p2; int ****p4 = &p3; int *****p5 = &p4; int ******p6 = &p5; int *******p7 = &p6; int ********p8 = &p7; int *********p9 = &p8; ft_multipointer(p9); printf("%d\n", v);` OK, you could call `ft_multipointer(&p8)` and do without `p9`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually you wouldn't need that many pointers, but it's possible that you want to pass a pointers or pointers to pointers around. You could also use pointers to dereference multi-dimensional data structures.
2. nbr is just the variable name and you can use any other valid sequence of letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely rare to see more than three levels of indirection (e.g. `int ***nbr`).  I can't think of any practical situation where you'd need *nine* levels of indirection, but my experience isn't that broad.

There are a couple of situations where multiple levels of indirection come up.  First is when you need a function to write to a parameter of pointer type.  Imagine you have something like the following:

```
void foo( T *ptr ) // for any type T
{
  *ptr = new_T_value(); // write a new value to the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;
  foo( &var ); // write a new value to var
  ...
}
```

We want `foo` to update the value in `var` - to do so, we must pass a pointer to `var`.  Now let's replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`:

```
void foo( P **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_Pstar_value(); // or **ptr = new_P_value(), assuming **ptr is valid
}

void bar( void )
{
  P *var;
  foo( &var );
  ...
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same, all that's changed is the type of the object we want to update.  We can take it another level by replacing `P` with another pointer type `Q *`:

```
void foo( Q ***ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_Qstarstar_value(); // or ***ptr = new_Q_value(), assuming ***ptr is valid
}

void bar( void )
{
  Q **var;
  foo( &var );
  ...
}
```

And on and on and on.  A quick check of the language definition doesn't seem to indicate a maximum level of indirection, but I may just be missing it.  Of course, you don't do what I did for the heck of it, you do it because you're really dealing with that many levels of indirection for whatever reason.

Multiple indirection also comes up when you're dealing with multi-dimensioned data.  Instead of using an N-dimensional array, you dynamically allocate memory - you create a pointer to a sequence of pointers, each of which points to a sequence of pointers, etc.:

```
/**
 * Dynamically allocate space for an NxMxL array - error checking
 * omitted for brevity.
 */
T ***p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );             // Allocates space for N objects of type T **
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  p[i] = malloc( M * sizeof *p[i] );          // Allocates space for M objects of type T *
  for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
    p[i][j] = malloc( L * sizeof *p[i][j] );  // Allocates space for L objects of type T
}
```

which gives you a structure like this:

```
   T ***      T **            T *                     T
   +---+      +---+           +---+                  +---+
p: |   | ---> |   | p[0] ---> |   | p[0][0] -------> |   | p[0][0][0]
   +---+      +---+           +---+                  +---+
              |   | p[1] -+   |   | p[0][1] -----+   |   | p[0][0][1]
              +---+       |   +---+              |   +---+
               ...        |    ...               |    ...
                          |                      | 
                          |   +---+              |   +---+
                          +-> |   | p[1][0] ---+ +-> |   | p[0][1][0]
                              +---+            |     +---+
                              |   | p[1][1] -+ |     |   | p[0][1][1]
                              +---+          | |     +---+
                               ...           | |      ...
                                             | |
                                             | |     +---+
                                             | +---> |   | p[1][0][0]
                                             |       +---+
                                             |       |   | p[1][0][1]
                                             |       +---+
                                             |        ...
                                             | 
                                             |       +---+
                                             +-----> |   | p[1][1][0]
                                                     +---+
                                                     |   | p[1][1][1]
                                                     +---+
                                                      ...
```

Again, in my experience I've never seen anything that required more than three dimensions to store, but my experience isn't that broad.  There may be some problem domains where you really do have 9 separate dimensions of data (`x = a[i][j][k][l][m][n][o][p][q];`), but I just haven't seen it.